# Flow: ensure the any type isn't used within a file

Tags: flowtype

Is there a way to ensure that the `any` type isn't used within a file? For instance, if a third party library doesn't have type definitions, meaning its imports have the `any` type, I'd like a warning or error.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed) along with [eslint-plugin-flowtype](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-flowtype#no-weak-types). (I never tested this, but maybe it works)

`flow-typed` downloads typedefs for your dependencies from a repository, and generates empty type definitions for the ones missing from the repo.
By empty, I mean it will generate typedefs with `any` types everywhere.

`eslint-plugin-flowtype` has a `no-weak-types` option, that warns against the use of weak types  (any, Object and Function) in your files.

Maybe you could configure `eslint` to check the files generated by `flow-typed`, and you would get warnings every time a `any` type appears in those files.

Comment: Hmm, my experience is that when requiring modules that aren't typed, Flow infers the type as `any`.

Comment: You seem to be right. That doesn't invalidate my suggestion, however. You could still try what you want using flow-typed, as I suggested. I will edit my answer.